# Python cannot bind requests to network interface

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I cannot use request proxy to connect to https with my local ip
192.168.1.55 is my local ip

if i hide the https line for proxy, it works, but i know that it is not actually using the proxies

```
import requests

ipAddress = '192.168.1.55:80'
proxies = {
  "http": "%s" % ipAddress,
  #"https": "%s" % ipAddress,
}

url = 'https://www.google.com'
res = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
print res
```

Result: Response [200]

```
import requests

ipAddress = '192.168.1.55:80'
proxies = {
  "http": "%s" % ipAddress,
  "https": "%s" % ipAddress,
}

url = 'https://www.google.com'
res = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
print res
```

Result:

requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 400 Bad Request',)))

I also tried external VPN server which support HTTPS protocol, even the https proxy line is un-hide, it will work

I have multiple IP and would like to use specified ip with the request.
I am running it on Win 10 with python 2.7, and I suspect it is due to the SSL problem, yet to confirm with expertise here. (i think i didnt deal with the SSL properly)
I tried a lot of ways to deal with the SSL, no luck so far.

Comment: What proxy server do you use?

Comment: The proxy server is the same PC as there are multiple public ip I can use in my PC, all I am trying is to balance out the outbound traffic with various public ip to send out request

Comment: I mean port `80` bind to what application?

Comment: When I use external VPN server, it does not require the port. In my case I believe 80 is bind to http in MS Window HTTP? I saw it in MS IIS. However, even I change th eoort to 443 (which I believe it is for HTTPS, it still doesn't work). Therefore I am suspecting it is SSL issue. However I cannot prove it and neither solve it at the moment

Comment: so you don't have proxy server but want to bind `requests` to use 192.168.1.55 instead of default connection?

Comment: Whether I have proxy server for https - not sure. But http can go through without issue, so I am not sure if I have to specifically setup a proxy server for https for not. And Yes. I want to bind request to use 192.168.1.55 instead of the default connection. Maybe proxy isnt the right lib to do so? I am welcome to other approach if you may suggest

Answer (score 4):

you can try this to bind `requests` to selected adapter/IP but first install `requests_toolbelt`

```
pip install requests_toolbelt
```

then

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.adapters.source import SourceAddressAdapter

# default binding
response = requests.get('https://ip.tyk.nu/').text
print(response)

# bind to 192.168.1.55
session = requests.Session()
session.mount('http://', SourceAddressAdapter('192.168.1.55'))
session.mount('https://', SourceAddressAdapter('192.168.1.55'))
response = session.get('https://ip.tyk.nu/').text
print(response)
```

Comment: you're welcome, please consider mark the answer as correct.